# is there simple way to display React component and pass dynamic events?

Tags: reactjs

I have react code like this which display one of the react component depending on value of variable component . I am looking to avoid this if else block and make it more generic. is there any simple way to achieve this ?

```
  {
        component === 'component1' &&
            <component1
              componentData={componentData}
              onCancelClicked={goBackToHome}
              onAction1Clicked={(e) => onAction1Clicked(e)}/>

  }
  {
        component === 'component2' &&
            <component2
                componentData={componentData}
                onAction2Req={onAction2}
                onCancelClicked={goToCompnent4} />

  }
  {
          component === 'component3' &&
             <component3
                onCancelClicked={goBackToHome} />
  }
  {
          component === 'component4' &&
              <component4
                  onCancelClicked={goBackToHome}/>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const compoenentObj = {
  component1: <div>Component 1</div>,
  component2: <div>Component 2</div>
}

const component = 'component2'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      {compoenentObj[component]}

    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `switch case`
In production we do have such syntax.

[image]

in you case it would like this.

```
switch(component){
 case "component1":
   return <component1/>
 case "component2":
   return <component2/>
 case "component3":
   return <component3/>
 case "component4":
   return <component4/>
 default:
   return <app/>
```